# Cannot find /bin directory in Android Studio working directory

Tags: software-installation, android-studio, android-sdk

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed Android Studio in my system. I have followed the following steps:

1. Downloaded jdk latest version and added it to build path.
2. Downloaded Android SDK, unpacked it in `/usr/local/andriod-sdk-linux` .
3. Clicked on andriod.sh in `/tools` to download and install extra dependencies.

Now I am unable to locate `/bin` inside `/usr/local/andriod-sdk-linux`. I suppose I need studio.sh inside `/bin` to execute Android Studio.
Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: "/bin inside /usr/local/andriod-sdk-linux" why would there be one? *I* would assume it needs to be in a "bin" directory in your PATH (otherwise the instructions would need to have something like "add this {dir} to your PATH).

Comment: Android Studio and Android SDK, these are two completely different things. What do you have installed?

Comment: i have installed andriod sdk..

Comment: i have installed andriod sdk.. form what i can see is that all the dependency has been downloaded. So shall i just need eclipse to go ahead or do i need to install Andriod studio from start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Android Studio and Android SDK, these are two completely different things. First, you install Android Studio, then the SDK Tools.

---

<sub>[Source](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html#GetTools)</sub>

### Installing Android Studio

1. Unpack the downloaded archive file into an appropriate location for your applications.
2. To launch Android Studio, navigate to the `android-studio/bin/` directory in a terminal and execute studio.sh.

   You may want to add `android-studio/bin/` to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

### Installing Android SDK

1. **Click the marked button**

   [image]
2. **Get the latest SDK tools**

   As a minimum when setting up the Android SDK, you should download the latest tools and Android platform:

   1. Open the Tools directory and select:

      - Android SDK Tools
      - Android SDK Platform-tools
      - Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)
   2. Open the first Android X.X folder (the latest version) and select:

      - SDK Platform
      - A system image for the emulator, such as 
        ARM EABI v7a System Image
3. **Get the support library for additional APIs**

   The Android Support Library provides an extended set of APIs that are compatible with most versions of Android.

   Open the Extras directory and select:

   - Android Support Repository
   - Android Support Library
4. **Get Google Play services for even more APIs**

   To develop with Google APIs, you need the Google Play services package:

   Open the Extras directory and select:

   - Google Repository
   - Google Play services
5. **Install the packages**

   Once you've selected all the desired packages, continue to install:

   - Click Install X packages.
   - In the next window, double-click each package name on the left to accept the license agreement for each.
   - Click Install.